# Access locations in My Places of a particular account through Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps allow a user to add and group places in **My Places**. I would like to access the locations in a user's **My Places** programmatically instead of manually download the KML file. I did some search but could not find much helpful documentation or discussion on this topic. Apparently this is possible because [this iOS app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-places-for-google-maps/id492861440?mt=8) seems to be able to access it. The question is what Google Maps API or web services can provide this information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No one answers this question. I found how to do it after a few days of search.

1. Use google client login to get access_token for scope https://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/. Search Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Applications for documentation.
2. Access google maps data with the access token at https://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/maps/default/full?access_token=xxx.

Comment: Can you give more detail? I don't know how to do, there is no Maps feed in Google OAuth playground. Thanks.