# Api to access "My Places" spcifialy the Maps User have created

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I would like to access the Maps created by User on Google Maps (which are stored in "My Places" section).
Could you please suggest the API to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for accessing My Places :(

Comment: I tried doing this is there any clean way to get that auth token ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746189/how-to-get-list-of-my-places-from-google-maps-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Do look here for a possible solution. I'm not sure though.
[Maps and Places in Android implementation example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)